# how to backup some of the existing files present before unzip

Tags: ant, backup, unzip

I have some folders which are zipped together. I want to unzip the folders to some location or different, but if there exists the same file in .zip then I want to make a back up of the file in some location and then the UNZIP command will overwrite the file.

Comment: Can you write it more clearly? I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: i have zip file in location c:\temp\test.zip and the files are

Comment: a.txt,b.txt,c.txt, i want to unzip the test.zip to the location c:\update\temp where there exists the file name b.txt,c.txt , as doing to unzip command it will overwrite the existing files , so i want a backup of the existing files under c:\update\temp before unzip.... i hope now it is bit clear

Answer (score 0):

1. Unzip to a temp location.
2. Use the [`<present>` selector](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) to make a fileset of files in both original and temp locations (those that would be overwritten).
3. Use that fileset to [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) your files from the original location to a backup location.
4. Copy over all files from the temp location to the original location.
5. Delete your temp location.